# Sending mail using mailx

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to send mail using Mailx and uuencode with attachments using the following in a shellscript

```
attachments=uuencode file1 file1;uuencode file2 file2;

(echo BODY ; $attachments )| mailx -s "Attachments" -m someone@mail.com
```

For the above script only mail without attachment is sent,However when i use the following

```
(echo BODY ; uuencode file1 file1;uuencode file2 file2;)| mailx -s "Attachments" -m someone@mail.com
```

Now mail is sent with the attachments.

I'm fairly new shellscripting kindly help.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong quotes for command substitution:

```
attachments=`uuencode file1 file1;uuencode file2 file2`
```

or better

```
attachments=$( uuencode file1 file1;uuencode file2 file2 )
```

See the [Command Substitution section of the bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

And then use `echo` to output the variable content

```
(echo BODY ; echo $attachments )| mailx -s "Attachments" -m someone@example.com
```

Comment: This gives you the output, like you commented on my answer, but that won't send the attachment when you pipe it. You need to pipe the output of the command, so the first part `(echo BODY; $attachments)` needs whatever `$attachments` expands to to be a command, otherwise you'll hit some error like `Begin: Command not found`

Comment: @chrisb2244 Thanks I didn't notice the missing `echo`. I updated the answer.

Comment: `mailx` handles uuencoding of attachments on the fly. So why not `echo "body" | mailx -s "Attachments" -a file1 -a file2 someone@example.com` That seems easier.